# How to use RESTful webservice in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8

I am working on building a platform which uses Drupal's web-service functionality to provide the content over any platform. With Drupal 6 & 7 it was all good with conventional HTTP web-service. But as in new release it has decided to take it on next level of web-service by using RESTfull web-service. My question is How can I customize this RESTfull web-service to make it responsive on my request from any other platform?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

go to site configuration and there restful webservice there click on it.and select all list which you want.after go throw instruction on it..